# Write string to file if this does not contain it already

Tags: python

I have a Python function that takes in a string and writes it into a text file. I changed that so it won't write a string if it exists already, but it doesn't seem to be working at all.

```
def log_folder(folder):
    fname = 'folder.log'
    fname_exists = os.path.isfile(fname)

    if not fname_exists:
       with open(fname,'a+') as outfile:
            outfile.write(folder+'\n')
    else:
         with open(fname,'r+') as inf:
              if folder not in inf.readlines():
                 inf.write(folder+'\n')
```

The expected result in the file is:

```
home/cyberbemon/20150203_220759+0000
home/cyberbemon/20150203_220759+0012
home/cyberbemon/20150203_220858+0000
```

What I'm getting is:

```
/home/cyberbemon/20150203_220759+0000
/home/cyberbemon/20150203_220759+0012
/home/cyberbemon/20150203_220858+0000
/home/cyberbemon/20150203_220759+0000
/home/cyberbemon/20150203_220759+0012
/home/cyberbemon/20150203_220858+0000
```

As you can see, they are still being written, even though they exist in the file.

Comment: You're probably handling newlines wrong. Try `print >>outfile, folder` (same for inf) instead of `.write()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are cheking if any line of the file is equals folder.
BUT you are storing folder+'\n' in each line.

You should change this line:

```
if folder not in inf.readlines():
```

To:

```
if folder+'\n' not in inf.readlines():
```